# Why is "in list" faster than checking individual elements?

Tags: python, performance

I have completed this challenges part two: https://adventofcode.com/2022/day/21 .

This is the code which I came up for it: (i have uploaded the input to the program [here](https://pastebin.com/KzrqKbw3))

```
import sys
import pstats
import time
#def f8_alt(x):
#    return "%14.12f" % x
#pstats.f8 = f8_alt
#PART2 = True
RUN_COUNT = 1000
glob_input = None
def parse_monkeys() -> dict:
    global glob_input
    if glob_input == None:

        glob_input = sys.stdin.read()
    
    lines = glob_input.split("\n")
    # Each line represents one monkey.
    # Each monkey name is four characters long. The line is of the format aaaa: bbbb + cccc

    out_dict = {}
    types = {}

    for line in lines:
        #print("line == "+str(line))
        monkey_name = line[:4]
        expression = line[6:]
        #out_dict[monkey_name] = expression.split(" ")
        #print("expression == "+str(expression))
        if expression.isnumeric():
            out_dict[monkey_name] = [expression]
            types[monkey_name] = 1 # one means number, zero means other expression
            continue
        types[monkey_name] = 0
        out_dict[monkey_name] = [expression[0:4], expression[5], expression[7:]]

    return out_dict, types


'''
def parse_monkeys() -> dict:
    stdin_input = sys.stdin.read()
    lines = stdin_input.split("\n")
    # Each line represents one monkey.
    # Each monkey name is four characters long. The line is of the format aaaa: bbbb + cccc

    out_dict = {}

    for line in lines:

        monkey_name = line[:4]
        expression = line[6:]
        out_dict[monkey_name] = expression.split(" ")

    return out_dict
'''


def evaluate_monkeys(monkeys: dict, cur_monkey: str) -> int:
    #if cur_monkey == "humn" and PART2:
    #   print("Error!")
    #   exit(1)
    tokens = monkeys[cur_monkey]
    if len(tokens) == 1:
        token = tokens[0]
        if token.isnumeric():
            return int(token) # plain number
        else:
            return evaluate_monkeys(monkeys, token)
    else:
        val_1 = evaluate_monkeys(monkeys, tokens[0])
        val_2 = evaluate_monkeys(monkeys, tokens[2])
        op_string = tokens[1]
        match op_string:
            case "+":
                return val_1 + val_2
            case "-":
                return val_1 - val_2
            case "*":
                return val_1 * val_2
            case "/":
                return (val_1 // val_2)
            case _:
                print("Invalid operation for monkey "+str(monkey_name)+" : "+str(op_string))
                exit(1)


def get_route(monkeys: dict, wanted_monkey: str, moves: list, cur_monkey: str, types: dict):

    if cur_monkey == wanted_monkey:
        #print("Returning moves")
        return moves
    #print("start")
    for monkey in monkeys:
        if types[monkey]:
            continue
        expression = monkeys[monkey]
        if cur_monkey in expression:

            if cur_monkey == expression[0]:
                #print("left")
                return get_route(monkeys, wanted_monkey, [0]+moves, monkey, types)
            else:
                return get_route(monkeys, wanted_monkey, [1]+moves, monkey, types)


'''

def get_route(monkeys: dict, wanted_monkey: str, moves: list, cur_monkey: str, types: dict):

    if cur_monkey == wanted_monkey:
        #print("Returning moves")
        return moves
    #print("start")
    for monkey in monkeys:
        if types[monkey]:
            continue
        expression = monkeys[monkey]

        if cur_monkey == expression[0]:
            #print("left")
            return get_route(monkeys, wanted_monkey, [0]+moves, monkey, types)
        elif cur_monkey == expression[2]:
            return get_route(monkeys, wanted_monkey, [1]+moves, monkey, types)

'''



def get_value(monkeys: dict, route: list):
    if route[0] == 0:
        # The humn leaf is on the left so the other value is on the right side.
        #value_monkey = monkeys["root"].split(" ")[2]

        value_monkey = monkeys["root"][2]
    else:
        # The humn leaf is on the right side, so the other value is on the left side
        #value_monkey = monkeys["root"].split(" ")[0]
        value_monkey = monkeys["root"][0]
    # Calculate lhs

    # def evaluate_monkeys(monkeys: dict, cur_monkey: str) -> int:

    lhs = evaluate_monkeys(monkeys, value_monkey)

    return lhs


def get_monkey_name(monkeys: dict, name: str, move:int):
    expression = monkeys[name]
    if move == 0:
        #return expression.split(" ")[0] # left
        return expression[0]
    else:
        #return expression.split(" ")[2] # right
        return expression[2]


def traverse_backwards(monkeys, route, value):

    # This function traverses the binary tree backwards to get the appropriate value for humn.

    # First get the monkey names which we traverse along to get to humn.

    cur_name = "root"
    monkey_names = ["root"]

    for move in route:
        cur_name = get_monkey_name(monkeys, cur_name, move)
        monkey_names.append(cur_name)

    #print("Monkey names which we traverse to get to humn: "+str(monkey_names))

    # reverse route and the monkey names along that route

    #monkey_names.reverse()
    #route.reverse()

    cur_name = "root"
    counter = 0
    monkey_names.pop(0)
    #print("monkey_names == "+str(monkey_names))
    route.pop(0)
    #print("monkey_names == "+str(monkey_names))
    #print("Initial value: "+str(value))
    while cur_name != "humn":
        cur_name = monkey_names[counter]
        # value is lhs
        #
        if cur_name == "humn":
            #print("qqqqqqqqqqqq")
            break
        if route[counter] == 1:
            # humn thing is on the right, so calculate left.
            cor_index = 0
        else:
            # humn is on the left so calculate right
            cor_index = 2
        tokens = monkeys[cur_name]
        other_monkey_name = tokens[cor_index]

        val_2 = evaluate_monkeys(monkeys, other_monkey_name)

        match tokens[1]: # Match operator and apply the reverse operator
            case "+":
                value = value - val_2
            case "-":
                # Same as with division:
                if cor_index == 0:
                    # Humn thing is on the right aka value = aaaa - humn => humn = aaaa - value
                    value = val_2 - value
                else:
                    # Humn thing is on the left, so value = humn - aaaa => humn = value + aaaa
                    value = value + val_2
            case "*":
                # sanity check
                #if value % val_2 != 0:
                #   print("counter == "+str(counter))
                #   print("value % val_2 != 0")
                #   exit(1)
                value = value // val_2
            case "/":
                if cor_index == 0:
                    # Left is constant, so the divisor is actually the human thing. value = x / humn => humn = value / x
                    value = value / val_2
                else:
                    # Right is constant, so just multiply by val_2
                    value = (value * val_2)
            case _:
                print("Invalid operation for monkey "+str(monkey_name)+" : "+str(op_string))
                exit(1)
        counter += 1
    return value


def get_monkey_names(monkeys: dict, route: list):

    cur_name = "root"
    monkey_names = ["root"]

    for move in route:
        cur_name = get_monkey_name(monkeys, cur_name, move)
        monkey_names.append(cur_name)
    return monkey_names


def solve_equation(monkeys: dict, types: dict) -> int:
    # First get the route to the humn monkey and reverse it.

    route = get_route(monkeys, "root", [], "humn", types)
    monkey_names = get_monkey_names(monkeys, route)

    value = get_value(monkeys, route)

    humn_value = traverse_backwards(monkeys, route, value)
    #print("humn_value == "+str(humn_value))
    return humn_value

def main() -> int:
    start_time = time.time()
    for _ in range(RUN_COUNT):

        monkeys, types = parse_monkeys()
        result = solve_equation(monkeys, types)
        #result = evaluate_monkeys(monkeys, "root") # find value of root.
        #print(result)
    end_time = time.time()
    tot_time = end_time - start_time
    print(str(RUN_COUNT)+" runs tooks "+str(tot_time)+ " seconds.")
    print("Average run time was "+str(tot_time / RUN_COUNT)+" seconds.")
    return 0

if __name__=="__main__":
    exit(main())
```

I am now wondering why the non-commented version of "get_route" is faster than the commented one, because when trying with the commented out version of get_route I am getting slower execution speeds for each run. It doesn't make sense for me because the `monkeys[monkey]` list has a list of tokens, if the monkey just yells a number, then it only has that token, but if it is an expression (aka `aaaa + bbbb` for example), then it has `["aaaa", "+", "bbbb"]` as its elements. When running this program with `python3 -m cProfile -s time prof.py < input.txt` I get this next results:

```
1000 runs tooks 20.217543363571167 seconds.
Average run time was 0.020217543363571167 seconds.
         9674013 function calls (7041013 primitive calls) in 20.218 seconds

   Ordered by: internal time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
70000/1000   14.009    0.000   14.009    0.014 prof.py:88(get_route)
2633000/69000    2.855    0.000    3.160    0.000 prof.py:59(evaluate_monkeys)
     1000    2.423    0.002    2.684    0.003 prof.py:11(parse_monkeys)
  4054000    0.262    0.000    0.262    0.000 {method 'isnumeric' of 'str' objects}
  2633000    0.211    0.000    0.211    0.000 {built-in method builtins.len}
        1    0.159    0.159   20.218   20.218 prof.py:259(main)
     1000    0.119    0.000    2.923    0.003 prof.py:159(traverse_backwards)
     1000    0.093    0.000    0.093    0.000 {method 'split' of 'str' objects}
   138000    0.039    0.000    0.039    0.000 prof.py:149(get_monkey_name)
     1000    0.033    0.000    0.059    0.000 prof.py:236(get_monkey_names)
   138000    0.010    0.000    0.010    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
     1000    0.003    0.000   17.375    0.017 prof.py:247(solve_equation)
     1000    0.001    0.000    0.380    0.000 prof.py:130(get_value)
     2000    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'pop' of 'list' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000   20.218   20.218 prof.py:1(<module>)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.print}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'read' of '_io.TextIOWrapper' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <frozen _sitebuiltins>:19(__call__)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'close' of '_io.TextIOWrapper' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000   20.218   20.218 {built-in method builtins.exec}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method _codecs.utf_8_decode}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <frozen codecs>:319(decode)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method time.time}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

But when I uncomment the other version and use it instead I get this:

```
1000 runs tooks 23.656423330307007 seconds.
Average run time was 0.023656423330307007 seconds.
         9674013 function calls (7041013 primitive calls) in 23.657 seconds

   Ordered by: internal time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
70000/1000   17.517    0.000   17.517    0.018 prof.py:109(get_route)
2633000/69000    2.818    0.000    3.104    0.000 prof.py:59(evaluate_monkeys)
     1000    2.392    0.002    2.672    0.003 prof.py:11(parse_monkeys)
  4054000    0.285    0.000    0.285    0.000 {method 'isnumeric' of 'str' objects}
  2633000    0.185    0.000    0.185    0.000 {built-in method builtins.len}
        1    0.155    0.155   23.656   23.656 prof.py:259(main)
     1000    0.120    0.000    2.874    0.003 prof.py:159(traverse_backwards)
     1000    0.096    0.000    0.096    0.000 {method 'split' of 'str' objects}
   138000    0.039    0.000    0.039    0.000 prof.py:149(get_monkey_name)
     1000    0.034    0.000    0.061    0.000 prof.py:236(get_monkey_names)
   138000    0.011    0.000    0.011    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
     1000    0.003    0.000   20.829    0.021 prof.py:247(solve_equation)
     1000    0.001    0.000    0.375    0.000 prof.py:130(get_value)
     2000    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'pop' of 'list' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000   23.657   23.657 prof.py:1(<module>)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.print}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'read' of '_io.TextIOWrapper' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <frozen _sitebuiltins>:19(__call__)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'close' of '_io.TextIOWrapper' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000   23.657   23.657 {built-in method builtins.exec}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <frozen codecs>:319(decode)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method _codecs.utf_8_decode}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method time.time}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

The other version is doing more comparisons with the `if cur_monkey in expression:` and then later with the `if cur_monkey == expression[0]:` check, but it is somehow faster. Are array accesses that slow in python?

Comment: Once you use a primitive, the work is being done in C rather than in Python. It's very normal for them to be fast; anything like a `__getitem__` means another stack frame &c.

Comment: In general, btw, it's always a good idea to look at the `dis.dis` output for the things you want to compare so you can see the actual work involved in either route.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks! I looked at the disassembly and yeah the CONTAINS_OP operator seems to be faster than array accesses. I figured that array accesses would be faster because with them there would be only two comparisons, when as with "in" there would be more.

Comment: Your initial expectation would probably be correct for a longer list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this is the difference in the low level bytecode. The disassembly of the slower version yields this as bytecode (disassembled):

```
124     >>  106 LOAD_FAST                3 (cur_monkey)
            108 LOAD_FAST                6 (expression)
            110 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
            112 BINARY_SUBSCR
            116 COMPARE_OP              40 (==)
            120 POP_JUMP_IF_TRUE         1 (to 124)
            122 JUMP_BACKWARD           52 (to 20)
```

when as the faster version yields this:

```
 99          48 LOAD_FAST                3 (cur_monkey)
             50 LOAD_FAST                6 (expression)
             52 CONTAINS_OP              0
             54 POP_JUMP_IF_TRUE         1 (to 58)
             56 JUMP_BACKWARD           19 (to 20)
```

Thanks to Charles Duffy for the answer!